# КУКУ и Опера

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, почему не работают КУКУ в браузере Опера, написал небольшую регистрацию, авторизацию и страницу с юзерамы на PHP MYSQL,все работает, вот только есть одно но..., в браузере Опера при авторизации, не сохраняются Куку, другие браузеры: Хром, Мазила и Safari КУКУ сохраняют, что в моей кода не так?

**login.php**

```
<?php
//Запускаем Сессию:
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }

//Если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку
if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {
    exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}

//Подключаем Базу Данных:
require_once ("database.php");

//Извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином
$result_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'",$db); 
$myrow_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_user);    
    if (empty($myrow_user['id'])) {
        exit ("ВЫ ВВЕДИ НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ");
    }
    else {
        //Если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию!
        $_SESSION['password'] = $myrow_user['password']; 
        $_SESSION['login'] = $myrow_user['login'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $myrow_user['id'];
        //Если пользователь хочет входить на сайт автоматически
        if (isset($_POST['save'])){
            setcookie("auto", "yes", time()+9999999);
            setcookie("login", $_POST["login"], time()+9999999);
            setcookie("password", $_POST["password"], time()+9999999);
            setcookie("id", $myrow_user['id'], time()+9999999);
        }
    }   
//Перенаправляем пользователя на его страничку
header("Location: http://network.com/users.php?id=$_SESSION[id]");

?>
```

**users.php**

```
<?php
//Запускаем Сессию
session_start();

//Подключаем Базу Данных:
require_once ("database.php");

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
}
//Если не указали ID, то выдаем ошибку
else { 
    header("Location: http://network.com/"); 
}

//Если ID не число, то выдаем ошибку
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
    header("Location: http://network.com/");
}
else {
    //Если существует логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем, действительны ли они
    if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
        $login = $_SESSION['login'];
        $password = $_SESSION['password'];
        $result_users_session = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'",$db); 
        $myrow_users_session = mysql_fetch_array($result_users_session);
        //Если не действительны 
        if (empty($myrow_users_session['id'])) {
            header("Location: http://network.com/tools.php?action=login");
        }
    }
    //Проверяем, зарегистрирован ли вошедший
    else {
        //Если не зарегистрированный, перенаправляем на страницу авторизации 
        header("Location: http://network.com/tools.php?action=login"); 
    }
    $result_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'",$db);
    //Извлекаем все данные пользователя с данным ID 
    $myrow_users = mysql_fetch_array($result_users);
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $myrow_users['login']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Пользователь "<?php echo $myrow_users['login']; ?>"</h2>
<?php
//Если страничка принадлежит вошедшему!
if ($myrow_users['login'] == $login) {
    echo "$myrow_users_session[name]";
    //Навигация:
print <<<HERE
    <br/>
    <a href='users.php?id=$myrow_users_session[id]'>Моя страница</a><br/>
    <a href='all_users.php'>Список пользователей</a><br/>
    <a href='logout.php'>Выход</a>
HERE;

}
//Если страничка чужая!
else
{
    echo "$myrow_users[name]";
    //Навигация:
print <<<HERE
    <br/>
    <a href='users.php?id=$myrow_users_session[id]'>Моя страница</a><br/>
    <a href='all_users.php'>Список пользователей</a><br/>
    <a href='logout.php'>Выход</a>
HERE;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: @amf1k, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Сколько я не всматривался в это безобразие, так и не увидел set_cookie()

Comment: а ты был просто невнимательный, посмотри ещё раз!, файл login.php! модераторы не отформатировали код!

Comment: @amf1k какие модераторы? Это ваша работа форматировать этьт поток сознания. Или думаете, у кого-то возникнет желание ковыряться в этом безобразии?

Comment: Всем сохранять спокойствие!  
Доеду до дома и отмодерирую.  
Покорнейше прошу прощения- с телефона неудобно выполнять свою работу.

Comment: @ReinRaus, я сам не буду форматировать и вам не советую, т.к. задавал вопрос не новичек и должен проявлять уважение, если хочет получить взамен такое же отношение. А это тупо наплевательское или даже потребительское уважение к тем, кто помогает.

Comment: не кто не поможет???

Comment: нужно в setcookie указывать path и domain ([документация][1]), тогда и будет работать во всех браузерах как следует.

[1]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: можно на моем примеры, я просто не разу не использовал path и domain!

Comment: Вы документацию читали вообще?
    setcookie("auto", "yes", time()+9999999, "/", ".example.com");

В вашем случае во всех браузерах куки оставляются, включая Оперу. Просто потом Опера просто напросто не может найти эти куки, а с остальными браузерами Вам просто повезло.

Comment: не работает)

Comment: покажите как Вы куки поставили? И удалили ли Вы все куки из браузера для чистоты эксперимента?

Answer (score 1):

поставь время +3600 посмотри пройдет оно?

Comment: <noscript>У вас отключен Javascript!</noscript>